# Vulkan, what variables does an object need? As in a separate mesh that can be updated individually

Tags: vulkan

So I have been experimenting, and I can add a new "object" by adding every model in the scene to the same vertex buffer, but this isn't good for a voxel game because I don't want to have to reorganize the entire world's vertices every time a player destroys a block.

And it appears I can also add a new "object" by creating a new vertex and index buffer for it, and simply binding both it and all other vertex buffers to the command buffers array at the same time like this:

```
        vkCmdBeginRenderPass(commandBuffers[i], &renderPassInfo, VK_SUBPASS_CONTENTS_INLINE);

        vkCmdBindPipeline(commandBuffers[i], VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS, graphicsPipeline);
        vkCmdBindDescriptorSets(commandBuffers[i], VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS, pipelineLayout, 0, 1, &descriptorSets[i], 0, nullptr);

        // mesh 1
        VkBuffer vertexBuffers[] = { vertexBuffer };
        VkDeviceSize offsets[] = { 0 };
        vkCmdBindVertexBuffers(commandBuffers[i], 0, 1, vertexBuffers, offsets);
        vkCmdBindIndexBuffer(commandBuffers[i], indexBuffer, 0, VK_INDEX_TYPE_UINT32);
        vkCmdDrawIndexed(commandBuffers[i], static_cast<uint32_t>(indices.size()), 1, 0, 0, 0);

        // mesh 2
        VkBuffer vertexBuffers2[] = { vertexBuffer2 };
        vkCmdBindVertexBuffers(commandBuffers[i], 0, 1, vertexBuffers2, offsets);
        vkCmdBindIndexBuffer(commandBuffers[i], indexBuffer2, 0, VK_INDEX_TYPE_UINT32);
        vkCmdDrawIndexed(commandBuffers[i], static_cast<uint32_t>(indices.size()), 1, 0, 0, 0);

        vkCmdEndRenderPass(commandBuffers[i]);
```

But then this requires me to bind ALL vertex buffers to the command buffers array every time even when only a single one of those meshes is updated or created/destroyed. So how would I "add" a new "game object," the vertices and indices of which can be updated without having to loop through everything else in the scene too? Or is it relatively quick to bind to an already calculated vertex and index buffer and this is standard?

And I have tried this with a command buffer per object:

```
 VkSubmitInfo submits[] = { submitInfo, submitInfo2 };

    if (vkQueueSubmit(graphicsQueue, 2, submits, inFlightFences[currentFrame]) != VK_SUCCESS) {
        throw std::runtime_error("failed to submit draw command buffer!");
    }
```

But it only renders the last object in the queue (it will render the first object if I say the submit size is 1).

I have tried adding a separate descriptorset, descritor pool, and pipeline as well and it still only renders the last command buffer in the queue. I tried adding a new commandpool for each object but `commandPool` is used by dozens of other functions and it really seems like there is supposed to be only one of those.

Comment: This is more of a general voxel game question than a vulkan specific one i think...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You split your world into chunks, and draw one chunk at a time. All chunks have some space reserved for them in (a single) vertex buffer, and when something has changed, you only update that one chunk. If a chunk grows too large... Well, you will probably need some sort of a memory allocation system.

Do NOT create separate buffers for every little thing. Buffers just hold data. Any data. You can even store different vertex formats for different pipelines in one same buffer - just in different places within it and binding it with an offset. Do not rebind just to draw a different mesh if all your vertices are packed neatly into array (they most likely are). If you want to only draw a part of a buffer - just use what draw commands give you.

Command buffers are just a block of instructions for the gpu. You dont need one per object. However, one cannot be used and written to at the same time, so you will need at least one per frame in flight and one to write to. Pipelines(descriptor sets, and pretty much whatever else you bind) are just a bunch of state that your gpu starts using once you bind it. At the start of command buffer, the state is undefined - it is NOT inherited between command buffers in any way.

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful. How do I use the offset? And giving them enough spacing in a buffer would often lead to empty spaces in that buffer I'd have to somehow skip over? What might that look like instead of this `vkCmdBindVertexBuffers(commandBuffers[i], 0, 1, &vertexBuffer, 0);` Thank you again.

Comment: And that means I'd have to update the entire vertex buffer before re-binding it, right? It looks like I can bind at an offset, but I can't update a buffer at an offset, can I? I have to recreate a new buffer and then copy it to the vertex buffer. So it just moves the problem to the vertex buffer (and index buffer too obviously), is this ok? If I have millions of vertices in my scene, won't it take a while to copy that entire buffer every time I update a mesh?

Comment: [CmdBindVertexBuffers](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/man/html/vkCmdBindVertexBuffers.html) just tells your draw comands where to take vertices from. `CmdDraw*` has `firstIndex` and `vertexOffset` values, which let you pick vertices and indices at an offset (if they are packed as an array). Why exactly do you think you can't partially update your buffer? [CmdCopyBuffer](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/man/html/vkCmdCopyBuffer.html) lets you specify offsets and size of copy.

Comment: You also don't need to create a new buffer each frame... Just have one/two that you write to from CPU, and then copy from them to GPU memory to points where it should be. Just don't destroy them until you exit the application

Comment: Oh ok so to update the vertex buffer, I just create (and reuse) a small staging buffer of just that "object" and then copy that into the vertex and index buffers at the appropriate offsets with `vkCmdCopyBuffer`? Or does the staging buffer have to be the same size as the destination buffer?